# How to get and apply the gradient from a regression line of standards on measured values in R

Tags: r, atmosphere

I am trying to apply a standard regression line to gas data. The data looks like the data.frame below. The valve number indicates if the CO2 is a sample=out_air (1) or a standard (2). In my standards I only use the mean of the last 5 measurements per standard measurement row (10 x). I want to calculate a regression line between these two means. Afterwards, its gradient should be applied on the out_air samples which were measured in the meantime. Any ideas? I have a lot more data and standard rows why I need a script which can be applied on repetitive measurements.

```
              Date    CO2     CH4 CO_LGR N2O_LGR Ventil      date_unconv
1     31.01.2018 00:02 410.87 1927.30 119.63  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:02
2     31.01.2018 00:03 410.99 1925.54 119.47  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:03
3     31.01.2018 00:04 410.91 1926.99 119.59  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:04
4     31.01.2018 00:05 410.91 1926.90 119.64  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:05
5     31.01.2018 00:06 410.88 1927.38 119.70  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:06
6     31.01.2018 00:07 410.97 1925.69 119.51  328.25      1 31.01.2018 00:07
7     31.01.2018 00:08 410.95 1926.71 119.61  328.24      1 31.01.2018 00:08
8     31.01.2018 00:09 410.93 1926.80 119.65  328.21      1 31.01.2018 00:09
9     31.01.2018 00:10 410.90 1926.91 119.61  328.21      1 31.01.2018 00:10
10    31.01.2018 00:11 410.92 1926.72 119.61  328.24      1 31.01.2018 00:11
11    31.01.2018 00:12 410.96 1926.40 119.57  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:12
12    31.01.2018 00:13 410.86 1927.34 119.70  328.21      1 31.01.2018 00:13
13    31.01.2018 00:14 410.92 1926.67 119.67  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:14
14    31.01.2018 00:15 410.96 1926.23 119.65  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:15
15    31.01.2018 00:16 410.91 1927.37 119.74  328.24      1 31.01.2018 00:16
16    31.01.2018 00:17 410.92 1927.19 119.68  328.21      1 31.01.2018 00:17
17    31.01.2018 00:18 410.95 1927.18 119.71  328.21      1 31.01.2018 00:18
18    31.01.2018 00:19 410.90 1927.76 119.77  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:19
19    31.01.2018 00:20 410.99 1926.46 119.66  328.24      1 31.01.2018 00:20
20    31.01.2018 00:21 411.01 1925.92 119.59  328.23      1 31.01.2018 00:21
21    31.01.2018 00:22 410.89 1927.16 119.68  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:22
22    31.01.2018 00:23 410.90 1927.05 119.72  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:23
23    31.01.2018 00:24 410.89 1927.20 119.72  328.22      1 31.01.2018 00:24
                  Date    CO2     CH4 CO_LGR N2O_LGR Ventil      date_unconv
300   31.01.2018 05:01 404.88 1864.68 113.73  332.79      2 31.01.2018 05:01
301   31.01.2018 05:02 403.02 1849.81 118.14  335.29      2 31.01.2018 05:02
302   31.01.2018 05:03 403.01 1849.74 117.92  335.32      2 31.01.2018 05:03
303   31.01.2018 05:04 403.02 1849.80 117.87  335.33      2 31.01.2018 05:04
304   31.01.2018 05:05 403.00 1849.79 117.86  335.32      2 31.01.2018 05:05
305   31.01.2018 05:06 403.02 1849.88 117.85  335.34      2 31.01.2018 05:06
306   31.01.2018 05:07 403.02 1849.73 117.87  335.34      2 31.01.2018 05:07
307   31.01.2018 05:08 403.01 1849.77 117.84  335.35      2 31.01.2018 05:08
308   31.01.2018 05:09 403.01 1849.76 117.83  335.32      2 31.01.2018 05:09
309   31.01.2018 05:10 403.01 1849.75 117.84  335.31      2 31.01.2018 05:10
```

**......**

This is what I have written so far:

```
    Dat <- data.frame
# declare time 
Dat$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Dat$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT"))

#different valve datasets
out_air <- Dat[Dat$valve==1,]
work_std <- Dat[Dat$valve==2,]

# mean Std, out of last 5 values of the 10 measurements each
MeansCO2 <- apply(as.data.frame(matrix(work_std$CO2, nrow=10)[6:10,]),2,mean) 

# Date of last Std measurement time
Date4means <- work_std$Date[seq(10,nrow(work_std),10)]

# dataframe for Std means and date
StdMeans <- data.frame(Date4means, MeansCO2)


# using one minute later than last std cal in out_air dataset; This is not working for all std.’s since there were also other numbers in Ventile column which I have not mentioned because they are not important for my question 

stdcal <- which(is.element( out_air$Date, StdMeans$Date4means+60))
out_air$std_m <- ifelse(is.element( out_air$Date, StdMeans$Date4means+60), StdMeans$MeansCO2, NA) # some means are missing 
out_air$std <- out_air[stdcal,]

# dataset without outlier
out_air_small <- out_air[out_air$CO2<500,]

library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
plot_CO2 <- xyplot(CO2 ~ Date, data=out_air_small, ylim=400:430)
plot_CO2 + as.layer(xyplot(std_m ~ Date, data=out_air_small,col="red",pch = 4, cex = 1))

# plot is made out of all data I have with red X indicating the standards:
```

[xyplot of all CO2 data (blue) and standards (red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbfG.jpg)

```
I also tried to calculate the gradient by using this function:

gradient <- function(data, stdcal,parameter, Date){
  x       <- seq(1,length(stdcal),1)
  y       <- data$parameter[stdcal]
  y1      <- y[which(data$parameter)]
  pos_y1  <- stdcal[x]
  x1      <- as.numeric(data$Date[pos_y1])
  y2      <- y[x+1]
  pos_y2  <- stdcal[x+1]
  x2      <- as.numeric(data$Date[pos_y2])
  m       <- (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
  b       <- y1 - m*x1 
  grad    <- m*(as.numeric(data$Date[stdcal])) + b
  grad
  }
gradient(data=out_air, stdcal, parameter = CO2, Date)
# without success as I cannot use this date format and also no success when I use the unformated date version.
```

Your help is greatly appreciated as I am working on this for a while now.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you go over your calculation with a smaller dataset (say 10 rows)?

Comment: Thank you for your question. This dataset I showed you is just an example. There are a lot more data measured in between and it is not equally distributed.. I need a fuction which can be easily applied on big datasets.

Comment: Understood but I don't get the calculation and what exactly is not working in there.

Comment: Trying to calculate the gradient of my regression line I need 2 X values which are x1 and x2 here. X is actually the date and Y the measured values. In this function I cannot use the date format as R cannot calculate with them. Therefore, the whole function is not working and I do not know and find another way to get this regression line. Do you have an idea how I can get over the format problem or do you even have a different way to calculate this regression line?

Answer (score 0):

The calculations you seem to want would not work for the data you've shared. Anyway, here's what seems to work:

**DATA**

```
library(data.table) # makes it easier to query/subset datasets
dt <- as.data.table(read.delim("clipboard", header = T, sep = "|"))
setnames(dt, c("Date", "CO2"), c("date", "co2"))
dt$date <- as.POSIXct(dt$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

**CODE**

```
# Function to divide data.table into chunks of "n" observations and return mean value of 
# co2 for n/2 observations. 

retVals <- function(z, chunk = 10){
  n <- nrow(z)
  r <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk), each = chunk)[1:n]

  # Split data.table into chunks - set to 10 based on the question
  dat_list <- split(z, r)
  ret_list <- lapply(dat_list, function(q){

    # averaging second half of an observation set set midval <- 5  if you only want the
    # last 5 observations to be averaged, regardless of the chunk size 

    midval <- ceiling(nrow(q)/2)
    return(data.table(date = q$date[nrow(q)], 
                      co2 = mean(q$co2[midval:nrow(q)], na.rm = T) ))
  })
  return(rbindlist(ret_list, use.names = T, fill = T))
}
```

Here's some output:

```
> retVals(dt[valve == 1])
                  date    co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:13:00 410.92
2: 2018-01-31 00:33:00 410.90
> retVals(dt[valve == 2])
                  date      co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:23:00 410.9400
2: 2018-01-31 00:43:00 410.9133
```

Function to get value of `co2` for a current time plus some constant time interval (`time_interval`) from a given dataset:

```
out_air <- dt[valve == 1, ]
work_std <- dt[valve == 2, ]

nextObv <- function(tme, dat = out_air, time_interval = 60){
  dat_sub <- dat[date == tme + time_interval, ]
  retval <- NA
  if(nrow(dat_sub) > 0){
    retval <- mean(dat_sub$co2)
  }
  return(retval)
}
```

Some output:

```
> q <- retVals(dt[valve == 1])
> q
                  date    co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:13:00 410.92
2: 2018-01-31 00:33:00 410.90
> q[, next_min_co2 := nextObv(date, dat = work_std), by = date]
> q
                  date    co2 next_min_co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:13:00 410.92       410.92
2: 2018-01-31 00:33:00 410.90       410.90
```

Here `q` is the dataset for outside air (`valve == 1`) wherein, `date` is the last date of every chunk of 10 observations and `co2` is the mean value of `co2` for the latter half of those 10 observations. The data you posted (`dt`) had 20 observations with `valve == 1` which means two chunks of size 10 each and that's why we have 2 observations in `q`.

In the second step, for each observation I get the value of `co2` from `work_std` that is recorded a minute later. I used `work_std` but you could simply call `dt[valve == 2]` with the same result:

```
> q[, next_min_co2 := nextObv(date, dat = dt[valve == 2]), by = date]
> q
                  date    co2 next_min_co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:13:00 410.92       410.92
2: 2018-01-31 00:33:00 410.90       410.90
```

The above values are accurate based on the logic provided in the question. All of above code should work for your entire dataset.

Furhter, based on the logic that observatiosn with `co2 < 500` are outliers, the entire data set is an outlier. I'm not sure what "gradient" you want to calculate. If you're interested in finding a linear equation of `co2` vs `date`, you could use:

```
lm(co2 ~ as.numeric(date), data = q)
```

It would be better to use elapsed time instead of the absolute time but I don't know your end goal.  If  you want something different, please indicated clearly in your question what you're looking for e.g. for a given instant, you want to find out the value of `(next_min_co2 - co2)/as.numeric(date)` or something else. Using numeric values in an example to show what calculations you want makes it easy for others to understand the same.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Using `approxfun` to get interpolated values for all times:

```
outModel <- approxfun(x = out_air$date, y = out_air$co2, method = "linear")
workModel <- approxfun(x = work_std$date, y = work_std$co2, method = "linear")

nextObv <- function(tme, model = outModel, time_interval = 60){
  return(model(tme + time_interval))
}

> q <- retVals(dt[valve == 2])
> q
                  date      co2
1: 2018-01-31 00:23:00 410.9400
2: 2018-01-31 00:43:00 410.9133
```

`approxfun` interpolates between known data points to output the expected value. In your case since the data can be discontinuous, you can use an interpolated value instead. In the below example, we try two `time_intervals` - 60 and 30. Using 60 should return an exact value but 30 returns an interpolated value for the first row in `q`. The second row will show `NA` in both cases since that is outside the data range. We're using `outModel` so values are interpolated using the `out_air` dataset (same as `dt[valve == 1,]`) below:

```
> dt[valve == 1]
                   date    co2 valve
 1: 2018-01-31 00:04:00 410.91     1
 2: 2018-01-31 00:05:00 410.91     1
 3: 2018-01-31 00:06:00 410.88     1
 4: 2018-01-31 00:07:00 410.97     1
 5: 2018-01-31 00:08:00 410.95     1
 6: 2018-01-31 00:09:00 410.93     1
 7: 2018-01-31 00:10:00 410.90     1
 8: 2018-01-31 00:11:00 410.92     1
 9: 2018-01-31 00:12:00 410.96     1
10: 2018-01-31 00:13:00 410.86     1
11: 2018-01-31 00:24:00 410.89     1
12: 2018-01-31 00:25:00 410.88     1
13: 2018-01-31 00:26:00 410.90     1
14: 2018-01-31 00:27:00 410.91     1
15: 2018-01-31 00:28:00 410.93     1
16: 2018-01-31 00:29:00 410.94     1
17: 2018-01-31 00:30:00 410.94     1
18: 2018-01-31 00:31:00 410.88     1
19: 2018-01-31 00:32:00 410.87     1
20: 2018-01-31 00:33:00 410.84     1

> q$newvals <- nextObv(q$date)
> q
                  date      co2 newvals
1: 2018-01-31 00:23:00 410.9400  410.89
2: 2018-01-31 00:43:00 410.9133      NA

> q$newvals2 <- nextObv(q$date, time_interval = 30)
> q
                  date      co2 newvals newvals2
1: 2018-01-31 00:23:00 410.9400  410.89 410.8886
2: 2018-01-31 00:43:00 410.9133      NA       NA
```

If you don't want interpolated values, create a function to get the exact value first, if that returns `NA` then use `approxfun` to get an interpolated value. As I mentioned before, using elapsed time is a better way than using the exact time instant (look up `difftime` to get time interval b/w to dates).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! The retVals function is working quite well. I had to change retVals(dt[valve == 1]) to retVals(dt[dt$valve == 1,]) though. dat_sub <- dat[dat$Date == tme + time_interval, ]

Comment: Sorry, the comment was just sent through. In the second function nextObv I also had to change the first line to this dat_sub <- dat[dat$Date == tme + time_interval, ] . Here the output says [1] Date CO2 
<0 rows> (or row.names with length 0). Applying the function on q: q[, next_min_co2 := nextObv(Date,dat = work_std), by = Date] it replys this answer: 
Error in eval(bysub, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : 
  object 'Date' not found. Do you know why it cannot find "Date"?

Comment: Answering the other questions: In my code I produced an extra dataset without outliers by this: # dataset without outlier
out_air_small <- out_air[out_air$CO2<500,] which does not mean that CO2 < 500 is an outlier but CO2 >= 500 (outlier) is excluded from this dataset. My endgoal is to add the gradient of each regression line stemming from the two standard means respectively (before first out_air CO2 sample and after last out_air CO2 sample measurement) to the measured out_air CO2 data measured in between. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Ok, q[, next_min_co2 := nextObv(date,dat = work_std), by = date] works now as I changed the capital letters to lower case letters. However, for next_min_co2, there are only NAs produced which I put the blame on the nextObs function and its mentioned line.

Comment: Do you know maybe a way not to use the time (+60) but the following row location or similar? In this way I could also use the standards which end not before a new out_air measurement row but a target (indicated by valve Nr 3, also measured, not shown in this dataset. I actually got rid of them in the data but this leads to time gaps why a time +60 sometimes do not catch the wanted data. You see it in the picture I uploaded in my question, the missing red X indicate such a case). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to include `library(data.table)` - with that you do not neet to use `dt$valve` or `dt$Date` when subsetting and all the other errors you're seeing should go away. You can go the package github page to get the latest version. Using row-numbers might not work since you're comparing two different data.tables. In the above example, `q$next_min_co2[1]` is not obtained from the next row (2nd) of the data.table passed on to `nextObv`. Using time makes sense,  formissing data, you may want to do a piecewise interpolation. Look up `approx` or `approxfun` - hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry for not replying but I am still trying to make it work. What I found is that you used chunks of the out_air samples. There are unequal measurement series in my real data.frame an therefore not necessarily divisible by 10. That is why I have tried to apply the first function (retVals) Std values: q <- retVals(dt[valve == 2]) (which works perfectly). Then I am still fighting with your second function (nextObv with dat = work_std).

Comment: That is the output of its application: q[, next_min_co2 := nextObv(date, dat = out_air), by = date]:  Error in `==.default`(date, tme + time_interval) : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types . Do you know how I can handle this? Furthermore, I have no experience with approx function. If you have a quick start-up support I would greatly appreciate it :-) What I need is a tool to get over a measurement time gap when the next out_air measurement point is later than std mean+60. I hope you know what I mean. I am greatly thankful for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I changed all functions and the display of my data above. It seems as if it is finally working. I do not even need to interpolate. Thank you, @Gautam! I learnt a lot from your help!

```
    # declare time 
Dat$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Dat$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT"))

#different valve datasets
out_air <- Dat[Dat$Ventil==1,]
work_std <- Dat[Dat$Ventil==2,]
std <- Dat[Dat$Ventil==3 | Dat$Ventil==4 ,] # not visible in the uploaded data
tgt <- Dat[Dat$Ventil==5,] # not visible in the uploaded data

# mean Std's, using last 5 values of the 10 measurements each
MeansCO2 <- apply(as.data.frame(matrix(work_std$CO2, nrow=10)[6:10,]),2,mean) 
MeansCH4 <- apply(as.data.frame(matrix(work_std$CH4, nrow=10)[6:10,]),2,mean) 
MeansCO <- apply(as.data.frame(matrix(work_std$CO_LGR, nrow=10)[6:10,]),2,mean) 
MeansN2O <- apply(as.data.frame(matrix(work_std$N2O_LGR, nrow=10)[6:10,]),2,mean) 

# Date of last Std measurement time
Date4means <- work_std$Date[seq(10,nrow(work_std),10)]

# dataframe for Std means and date
StdMeans <- data.frame(Date4means, MeansCO2, MeansCH4,MeansCO,MeansN2O)

# location of std mean in dataframe
which(is.element( Dat$Date, StdMeans$Date4means))

#### CO2 ######
Dat$CO2_Std_MEAN<-ifelse(is.element( Dat$Date, StdMeans$Date4means), StdMeans$MeansCO2, NA) 
pos_Std_Dat <- which(!is.na(Dat$CO2_Std_MEAN))

# function to get gradients between the CO2 calibrations

xyplot(MeansCO2~Date4means,data=StdMeans, typ=c("l","p","r"))

CO2_gradients <- function(x,data=StdMeans){
  LM <- lm(MeansCO2[x:(x+1)]~Date4means[x:(x+1)])
  grad <- coef(LM)[2] # gives you the slope
  names(grad) <- names(Date4means)
  grad
}

CO2_slopes <- sapply(1:nrow(StdMeans), CO2_gradients) # apply on all cal std pairs
CO2_Dat_slope <- data.frame(StdMeans$Date4means, CO2_slopes) # make data.frame
CO2_Dat_slope

which(is.element( Dat$Date, CO2_Dat_slope$StdMeans.Date4means))

#add CO2_slope to big data.frame
Dat$CO2_slope<-ifelse(is.element( Dat$Date, CO2_Dat_slope$StdMeans.Date4means), CO2_Dat_slope$CO2_slopes, NA)

# make new data.frame including only out_air and work_std data
Dat_calCO2 <- Dat[Dat$Ventil==1| Dat$Ventil==2,]
pos_Std_mean <- which(!is.na(Dat_calCO2$CO2_Std_MEAN)) # location where mean std is


# apply the gradient on the measured CO2 data
CO2_cal <- function(x,data=Dat_calCO2){
  pos <- pos_Std_mean[x:(x+1)]                # use a position and the following 
  CO2_pos <- data$CO2[pos[1]:pos[2]]          # use a position and the following --> std and next std 
  CO2_corr <- CO2_pos * data$CO2_slope[pos_Std_mean[x]] + CO2_pos # apply gradient on CO2 data
  dat_new <- data.frame(data$Date[pos[1]:pos[2]],CO2_corr)# make data.frame
  colnames(dat_new) <- c("Date", "CO2_corr") # give names
  dat_new
}

# apply function on all CO2 sections, result is a list
CO2_corr_all <- sapply(1:(nrow(StdMeans)-1), CO2_cal) # including the last value would add NA that's why -1

# to get Date and Value pairs: in CO2_corr_all list the odd nr's are Dates, the equal nr's are the corrected CO2 values 
Data_Frame <-function(x, data=CO2_corr_all){
  trans <-t(data.frame(data[[x]], data[[x+1]] ))
  trans
}

# apply only on the odd nr's in the list
CO2_new <- sapply(seq(1,length(cbind(CO2_corr_all)),2),Data_Frame)
CO2_corr_data_t<-as.data.frame(CO2_new) # make data.frame
CO2_corr_data<-data.frame(t(CO2_corr_data_t))
colnames(CO2_corr_data)<- c("Date", "CO2_corr")

# convert into correct formats
CO2_corr_data$Date <- as.POSIXct(CO2_corr_data$Date, tz="GMT")
CO2_corr_data$CO2_corr <- as.numeric(levels(CO2_corr_data$CO2_corr))[CO2_corr_data$CO2_corr]

# add corr CO2 data to data.frame
Dat_cal$CO2_corr <-ifelse(is.element(Dat_cal$Date, CO2_corr_data$Date),CO2_corr_data$CO2_corr , NA)
```